# Diff operation in PostGIS/Geotools

Tags: postgis, features, geotools

How do I perform a diff operation on Postgis features/tables or Geotools objects?

Are there any automatic methods I can use?

If not, what would be the optimal way to implement your own diff?

For example, I have two versions of a Shapefile and I import them into two separate PostGIS tables.

What algorithm should I consider now?

How do I compare a geometry column and get a diff result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not absolutely clear what you are trying to do, but you may want to take a look at 
ST_Equals, ST_Difference functions.

http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/ST_Difference.html

http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/ST_OrderingEquals.html (if you expect things to be more or less exact)

http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/ST_Equals.html

Then you do a join something of form

```
SELECT t1.gid
  FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON ST_OrderingEquals(t1.geom, t2.geom)
WHERE t2.gid IS NULL;
```

Would give you all the gids that are not exactly represented in second table.